# Why do I get Complex numbers for energies using Hartree Fock equation?

Tags: schroedinger-equation, computational-physics, hamiltonian, eigenvalue, software

I am using [Hartree Fock approximation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hartree%E2%80%93Fock_method) to study the behavior of a many body system in an infinite potential Well, with the Harmonic Oscillator potential instead of the coulomb potential. My first guess functions are Sin functions, and I am getting complex values just in step one after solving the Hamiltonian.

Does any one know if getting Complex values for energy and coefficients make sense? Or I should look for a mistake in my program?

Comment: This sounds like you are not computing the energy correctly. The energy should be real regardless of the wavefunction.

Comment: Are you applying a discretization that does not preserve the Hermiticity of the Hamiltonian?

Comment: @Qmechanic No, my only boundary condition is the fact that I have a box from 0 to L.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Variation theorem tells you that with a trial wave-function you get energies greater than or equal to(equals when the trial wave-function hits the exact one) the actual energy. HF is basically a variational method. You should get real values. If you get a complex value, please check your code again. Look into the HF prescription again and see how the iteration is done until self consistency is achieved.